# Presto Pivoting Data

Tags: sql, pivot, presto, qubole

I am really new to Presto and having trouble pivoting data in it.
The method I am using is the following:

```
select
distinct location_id,
case when role_group = 'IT' then employee_number end as IT_emp_num,
case when role_group = 'SC' then employee_number end as SC_emp_num,
case when role_group = 'HR' then employee_number end as HR_emp_num
from table
where 1=1
and id = 1234
```

This is fine, however, null values are also populated for the rows and I would like to pivot the data, to only return one row with the relevant info.

[image]

I have tried using the array_agg function, which will collapse the data  but it also keeps the null values (e.g. it will return *null,301166,null* for the first colum)

Answer (score 0):

If only one row per location is needed you can use [`max`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#max) with group by:

```sql
select location_id, 
  max(IT_emp_num) IT_emp_num, 
  max(SC_emp_num) SC_emp_num, 
  max(HR_emp_num) HR_emp_num
from (
  select location_id,
    case when role_group = 'IT' then employee_number end as IT_emp_num,
    case when role_group = 'SC' then employee_number end as SC_emp_num,
    case when role_group = 'HR' then employee_number end as HR_emp_num
  from table
  where id = 1234)
group by location_id
```